# Jmeter Beanshell error

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

i am getting following error

```
     ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.*; import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import org.apache.jmet . . . '' Encountered "/" at line 15, column 74.
```

could anyone tell what is causing the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following approaches to debug your Beanshell script:

1. Add `debug();` line at the beginning of your script and inspect STDOUT so you will be able to see what exactly goes on
2. Add extra logging like `log.info("something");` so you will be able to determine which lines are fine and where execution stops by looking into *jmeter.log* file
3. Wrap your code into try/catch block as follows:

   ```
   try {
       //your Beanshell code here
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       log.info("Script execution failed", ex);
   }
   ```

Exception details will be printed to *jmeter.log* file, it's much more informative than `Error invoking bsh method` one.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more tips and tricks.

Answer (score 1):

can you post the full beanshell script please?

its likely you have a small syntax error in there. According to the error message, it will be on line 15.

Comment: thanks saviour,actually there were few errors in my script which were causing that prb?